# How to pass a button to another class and perform action when it's pressed?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class called `ApiWidget` which accepts a `child`, this child is going to be one which has `onPressed` in it, for example, an `ElevatedButton`.

I want to show this `onPressed` type child widget in this class but I want to perform some action when that button is pressed. How can I do that? I think `provider` is just not suitable here.

In other words, I just want to use the child button (for appearance) but I want to perform the operation in this class only.

```dart
class ApiWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  ApiWidget(this.child);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {}, // I want to perform some operation here when this child is pressed.
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Might be worthwhile to check which type of widget you have and then invoke their own onTap behavior. The [widget class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Widget-class.html) does not have the onTap behavior. You could check this using the [is keyword](https://dart.dev/faq#types).

Comment: @tomerpacific Yes, I know. But for simplicity, let's assume that I am only passing a widget which has `onPressed`.

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed explanation and an example of what it is exactly that you want to do?

Comment: How about using the `InkWell` widget?

Comment: @MaNDOOoo Thanks but that too won't work. I've answered my question but I'm happy to accept other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `onPressed` with the **dataType** `Function`.
Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GradientButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final VoidCallback onPress;

  GradientButtonWidget({
required this.title,
required this.onPress,
});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onTap,
        child: FittedBox(
          child: Text(title),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

The code you wrote looks like this:

```
class ApiWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final VoidCallback onPress;

  ApiWidget({
required this.child,
required this.onPress,
});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress, //This is how it is called
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @iDecode I sent a complete example of the classes made for this, and finally, I gave an example in your own code

Comment: you're right
You can use `VoidCallback` for `ElevatedButton` or `TextButton`

Comment: The `onPressed` of ElevatedButton will not let `GestureDetector.onTap` to invoke.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to wrap your `child` in `AbsorbPointer` or `IgnorePointer` widget. Doing so will ignore the `onPressed` of your button and you're free to perform the logic within that class.

If you also want to make sure your button receives `onPressed` event, you can do `(child as ElevatedButton).onPressed?.call()` in the `onTap` callback.

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    // Perform your operation...
  },
  child: AbsorbPointer(
    child: child, // Your passed button 
  ),
)
```

Comment: *I'm open to accept other answers if they provide a better solution*